# Occasional Exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) with Django web app after a successful Run

Tags: python, django, web-applications, pycharm, pydev

I am a newbie in Django annd also first time using Python. I am making use of Pycharm 2016.3.2 + Django IDE with Python 3.6.0 . Anyway I am keen to build a website with Django and starting with this tutorial here -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aX4XjwW4AJQ

Everything is going well apart from when I successfully run it for the first time and view the web app on browser. I then close the browser and close the Run/Debug session from the Debug window. After this, any subsequent attempts to run the Web app with report the following exit code for **Run**:

manage.py runserver 8000

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

**and for Debug**

runserver 8000

pydev debugger: process 10832 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 163.10154.50)

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

**From the research I have done so far, this seems to be because of the runserver command not exiting after a Run. Indeed, Pydev instruct to use CTRL-BREAK to close this but pressing this doesn't do anything for me, would appreciate any help?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out ticking the **No reload** option in the Run/Debug Configurations, all my nightmares instantly disappeared!!